# org-mode: capture templates - How to use them?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've started using `emacs`'s `org-mode` often, and finally I get to configure `org-capture`.

However, I've found in most places that one can configure different templates by adding the following lines to the `.emacs` file:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/Documents/Orgfiles/gtd.org" "Tasks")
     "* TODO %?\n %i\n %a")
    ("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree "~/Documents/Orgfiles/journal.org")
     "* %?\nEntered on %U\n %i\n %a")))
```

**Question**

- What is the purpose of using these templates?
- Could you (please) illustrate their uses with some examples?

Comment: These are used to save time for certain types of entries that are repetitive.  I have templates for tasks (things to do), and for events (appointments, holidays, birthdays, etc.).  Whatever information that is most commonly inserted is stored in the template.  You can even include a specific date, such as today for the deadline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`org-capture` lets you save (quickly!) links (in a broad sense) to you work for later reference. For example, say that you work on some `TeX` file, and you realize that you miss a section. Instead  of cutting your workflow, you simply hit `M-x org-capture` and save a quick note (with a *link* to the place in the `TeX` file) in your Get Things Done `org`-file.

In order to use this feature, you have to define certain files where you want to save those quick notes. For example, for me, the most important file is `gtd.org` where I accomulate all the todo's. In turn, it is useful to add this file to the agenda list (`M-x org-agenda-file-to-front`) so you can access easily todo lists.

The templates I use are defined as follows:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      (quote (("t" "todo" entry (file (concat org-directory "/gtd.org"))
               "* TODO %?\n%U\n%a\n" :clock-in t :clock-resume t)
              ("n" "note" entry (file (concat org-directory "/gtd.org"))
               "* %? :NOTE:\n%U\n%a\n" :clock-in t :clock-resume t)
              ("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree (concat org-directory "/diary.org"))
               "* %?\n%U\n" :clock-in t :clock-resume t)
              )))
```

And I mainly use the `t` for the todos. In practice, I binded (or maybe it is the default) `org-capture` to `C-c c` and then `C-c c t` opens a buffer where I can edit the todo item. Once I'm done `C-c C-c` saves the note in the predefined place, and I'm thrown automatically back to the buffer and point in the buffer where I was.

As always: for example `C-c` means that you have to hit the `CONTROC-c` combination and similarly `M-x` means that you have to hit `META-x` (`META` is normally `ALT`).

Comment: I just ran into a problem with a setup similar to this one, i.e. instead of an ordinary string for the file name I constructed one. That stopped working after a recent update and I had to modify it, `(concat org-directory "/gtd.org")` had to be changed to `(lambda () (concat org-directory "/gtd.org"))`.